# Understanding nested angle brackets in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm following a book about Typescript and I'm having a hard type figuring out the operations/castings that are being made with "<>".

For example, on the following code I'm not sure what is being declared as the type of the WrappedComponent.

Is it a ComponentType that also has PropsWithChildren and an initialState property? I really don't know how to read it.

How should I parse it? Any help is appreciated

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren, ComponentType } from 'react';
import { AppState } from './context/AppStateContext';

export const withData = (
  WrappedComponent: ComponentType<PropsWithChildren<{ initialState: AppState }>>
) => {
  // function code
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes between angle brackets are *types* being passed to something generic.

One way of thinking about it is to look at chained function calls in JavaScript:

```
foo(bar(123))
```

The above passes `123` into `bar`, then passes the result of that call into `foo`. Nested angle brackets in TypeScript do something similar; the inner types evaluate first, and then they get passed to the outer generic for *it* to parse.

So, this:

```
export const withData = (
  WrappedComponent: ComponentType<PropsWithChildren<{ initialState: AppState }>>
) => {
```

is like doing

```
type PropsWithChildrenIncludingState = PropsWithChildren<{ initialState: AppState }>;
type WrappedComponent = ComponentType<PropsWithChildrenIncludingState>;
export const withData = (
  WrappedComponent: WrappedComponent
) => {
```

except more concise.

The `PropsWithChildren` and `ComponentType` are generic types; they take a type argument and use that to evaluate to a different type.

If you aren't familiar with them yet, for a very simple example of a generic type:

```
type WrapInObject<T> = { prop: T };
type WrappedString = WrapInObject<string>;
```

results in `WrappedString` being interpreted as the type `{ prop: string; }`.

Comment: Thanks! That did help!